# Is having a database handle open through the whole runtime good practice?

Tags: mysql, c, database, sqlite

I did some research and may have missed better keywords for what I want to find out:

- Is it good practice to have something like a init_db() function that gives me a handler of the database at startup of a program and then close it when I exit the application.

Maybe to put more context: I'm trying to build a server executable in C, that should (in the best case) run non-stop / until updated, accessing a SQLite db.

- Also at what scale should I change from SQLite to MySQL. Maybe transactions per minute or size of db. Is there any chart for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to gain from reopening the database? Also, read [appropriate uses for SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Comment: I'm just curious if having a handler of the db open all the time and only closing it when I exit the program is a good practice.

Comment: Also would it drastically decrease speed if I reopen the connection for every access I have to the database?

Comment: Whether something is good practice is somewhat subjective. As for speed, you have to measure yourself.